# Forgot to grease ceramic pan for strata

Tags: ceramic, casserole

I made this [strata recipe](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/spinach-and-cheese-strata-107754), but in my haste, forgot to grease the pan. The ingredients are nicely layered at the moment, but Im worried about sticking. Its currently sitting for 8hrs to soak up the egg, but Im trying to decide if I should:

1. Just bake it
2. Dump the contents into a bowl, grease the pan, redump
   and bake a distinctly less beautiful non-strata strata.

Comment: (confused and not familiar with the dish...) The recipe doesn't call for greasing the pan, nor for turning it out—why would a bit of sticking be an issue?

Comment: @derobert It does... it says "*Spread one third of bread cubes in a **buttered** 3-quart gratin dish*". It, stupidly, doesn't call out buttering the dish as a step (a major peeve of mine) but it does say to butter the dish in passing.

Comment: @Catija ah, you are correct. I missed it. Agree with you about it should be its own step!

Comment: I'd keep it like it is and scrape the bottom for the crispy bits... :-) and leave the cleaning and scrubbing for later on!

Comment: I've made that mistake before, in both pyrex & corningware dishes.  It sticks some, but you can still scoop enough of it out that it's not a problem.  The only issue is that if you like the crispier bits, they stay stuck to the dish, so it's more custard-y than you'd otherwise have.

Answer (score 1):

If you're careful not to overcook it, it'll likely be fine. Eggy bready things will indeed eventually stick pretty badly, but if you pull it out when the eggs are just barely set all the way through, it won't have time to truly stick or burn on the bottom yet. I might bake it pretty high in the oven so that the top will be more likely to be well-browned in time.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that bread, being high-starch, is going to stick like crazy particularly when combined with egg, I guess it's your call. I would opt for rebuilding the strata, one way or another that strata is going to end up looking ugly, but it's going to also taste burned if you don't grease that pan.

Comment: Why would not greasing the pan cause it to taste burned?

Comment: I ended up cooking as it was. I didnt have any issues with it burning. In fact, it largely ended up being okay. I used a knife to separate the contents from the ceramic dish when it came out of the oven, and only had a little egg clinging to the bottom when I scooped it out. Dish was good.

Comment: @keyabob you might want to post this as an answer or an edit to your question